# Controlador no esta filtrando en php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filtro

Tengo un gran problema con un filtro de categorias de producto segun la sucursal a la que pertenecen, les muestro un ejemplo de como el filtro de marcas en este caso en ingles denominadas brand si funciona a la perfeccion sin embargo el filtro de categorias es como si no existiera, no importa lo que modifique en el filtro de categorias, no tiene efecto, he buscado todos los archivos que contienen la variables $lims_category_list y los he modificado como los muestro en la imagen sin embargo no tengo ningun resultado.

Creen que se deba a la manera en la que estoy nombra el filtrado de la categoria en php, el filtrado de las marcas es distinto pero al final entiendo que simplemente lo que hice fue reducir las lineas de codigo con las categorias.

Alguna idea ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al hacer un dd($lims_category_list) o un dd($lims_brand_list) te trae los resultados que necesitas?, por otra parte, en la base de datos estan los datos, valga la redundancia, que estas necesitando?

Comment: Lo mas extraño es que esta funcionando de manera correcta con las marcas que son las brand sin embargo con las categorías esta quedando sin efecto alguno. Efectivamente la base de datos tiene la información para poder filtrar.

Comment: Tienes que poner tu código como texto, no como imagen. Cómo esperas que intentemos reproducir el error?